# Remove leading, trailing and multiple space within a string in APL

Tags: string, apl

I've written a dfn in APL to remove leading, trailing and multiple space. Is there any other way to further improve it?

```
{a←(⍵∊' ') ⋄ b←((¯1↓(a,0)×(1,a))+(⌽∧\(⌽⍵)=' '))=0 ⋄ b/⍵} '  sad as    asdasd asd    '

o/p sad as asdasd asd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minor rewrite, just to remove parantheses and use boolean operators:

```
{a←⍵=' ' ⋄ b←~(¯1↓(a,0)∧(1,a))∨(⌽∧\⌽a) ⋄ b/⍵}
```

As a side-effect, it is also 16% faster ;-)

I'd also recommend to `)load dfns` and `)ed dxb` to learn from that fn which does the same even faster and also for matrices, nested data etc.

Answer (score 1):

Removing leading spaces:

```
{(+/×\' '=⍵)↓⍵}
```

You can remove from the right by reversing the string and run the same code.

Removing multiple spaces:

```
{(~'  '⍷⍵)/⍵}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading, trailing and multiple space

```
{(' '=1↑∆)↓(-' '=¯1↑∆)↓∆←(∼'  '⍷⍵)/⍵}
```

it is more efficient this way.